# #top positioning above the footer

Tags: html, css

I have this code HTML:

```
<div id="footer">

       <div id="container">                       

                     <div id="top"></div>


        </div> 


 <div id="footer2">
  <div id="meniu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?>
  </div> 
  <div id="copyright">
    <h1 id="text_c">© Codoban.com All rights reserved</h1>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>


</body>
```

And this is the CSS code:

```
#top {
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 38px;
    background: url(img/DESPRE-NOI.png) no-repeat;

}



#footer2
{ 
  text-align: center;
  border:0px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  background:url(img/BODY-MENU.png);
 margin:0px;
bottom:0px;
position: fixed;

}
```

What I want to do is align the #top above #footer as in the picture below.
[image]

If you apply `margin-top: X value` for a particular resolution is positioned ... if I move the laptop does not look good.

I tried all the solutions that we know ... even @media queries but still not working.

Can you please help me solve this problem?
I need to edit the HTML code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not place #top in #footer2?

Answer (score 0):

Set the absolute position to `#top`, `bottom: 80px` is just an example, don't know what exact position from bottom you need.

```
#top {position: absolute; bottom: 80px; left: 50%; margin-left: -200px}
```